# separate the burst part in regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm sure I used to know this, and I'm sure this is covered somewhere but since I couldn't find
I want to use regex to elicit the information that is required.
For example, the text is

> "!#man,money=23,save=10#!lweoi!#man,money=14,save=5#!hasg!#man,money=33,save=20#!"

So, I want to elicit all the 3 form and store it to arraylist but when I use the regex form

`"!#man,money=\\d+,save=\\d+#!"` it save all of it to one part.

How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: I became 3 mathces. I dont see a problem. https://regex101.com/r/7KKrTH/1

Comment: What values do you want store into arrayList? string or only number? show your code

Comment: !#man,money=23,sava=10#! savA or savE?

Comment: both of them first string then number

Comment: try adding groups? "!#man,money=(\\d+),save=(\\d+)#!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use group:

```
public class RegExpPsvm {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputStr = "!#man,money=23,save=10#!lweoi!#man,money=14,save=5#!hasg!#man,money=33,save=20#!";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("!#man,money=(\\d+),save=(\\d+)#!");

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String fullText = matcher.group(0);
            String manAndMoney = matcher.group(1);
            String save = matcher.group(2);
            System.out.println("fullText = " + fullText);
            System.out.println("manAndMoney = " + manAndMoney);
            System.out.println("save = " + save);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Point was matcher.group(0)